# How can I get every layers output value with keras?

Tags: neural-network, keras, time-series, lstm, layer

I want use keras Lstm to get the time series features, then use the features to Kmeans. But now I can not get the layers output values. How can I get the layers output values?

This is my lstm network

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

lstm_66 (LSTM)               (None, None, 50)          10400

---

lstm_67 (LSTM)               (None, 100)               60400

---

dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 101

---

## activation_19 (Activation)   (None, 1)                 0

I want to get the lstm_67 output values,my code is:

```
import keras.backend as K
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2' 
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
import numpy as np
statesAll=[]
layers = model.layers
print layers[1].output,type(layers[1].output[1]),sess.run(layers[1].output)
```

and the result is:

> Tensor("lstm_61/TensorArrayReadV3:0", shape=(?, 100), dtype=float32)

So, how can I get the layers output value?

Thanks!

But it not work,my code is:

```
def load_data(file_name, sequence_length=10, split=0.8):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=',', usecols=[1])
    data_all = np.array(df).astype(float)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    data_all = scaler.fit_transform(data_all)
    data = []
    print len(data_all)
    for i in range(len(data_all) - sequence_length - 1):
        data.append(data_all[i: i + sequence_length + 1])

    reshaped_data = np.array(data).astype('float64')
    np.random.shuffle(reshaped_data)
    x = reshaped_data[:, :-1]
    y = reshaped_data[:, -1]
    split_boundary = int(reshaped_data.shape[0] * split)
    train_x = x[: split_boundary]
    test_x = x[split_boundary:]

    train_y = y[: split_boundary]
    test_y = y[split_boundary:]

    return train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y, scaler

def build_model(n_samples, time_steps, input_dim):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(input_dim=1, output_dim=50,return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=1))
    model.add(Activation('linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
    print(model.layers)
    return model

def train_model(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y):
    model = build_model()
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=30,validation_split=0.1)
    return model


train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y, scaler = load_data(file path)
train_x = np.reshape(train_x, (train_x.shape[0], train_x.shape[1], 1))
test_x = np.reshape(test_x, (test_x.shape[0], test_x.shape[1], 1))

model = train_model(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y)

from keras import backend as K
layers = model.layers
K.eval(layers[1].output)
```

Answer (score 2):

In TensorFlow 2.x, you can do like this:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

model = build_model() 
# lstm_67 is the second layer.
lstm = K.function([model.layers[0].input], [model.layers[1].output])
lstm_output = lstm([test_x])[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

`keras.backend.eval()` should do.

Look at the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/eval) and [here](https://keras.io/backend/)

Comment: Thanks! But it not work,I add the code to the original questions,please help me.How can I get the model erery layers output feature values.

Comment: Maybe you can have  a look at this [link](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is a tensor, you need to use the `tf. Print ()` method to see the specific value. If you use Spyder, you will not see this information in the console. You need to execute this program in the command line.

Comment: I cant not understand your answer,Can you speak a little bit in detail?Thanks!

Comment: You can try this code:`tf.Print(layers[1].output)`.

Comment: Thanks! the code solve my problem:
        from keras import backend as K
        def get_activations(model, layer, X_batch):
            get_activations = K.function([model.layers[0].input,   K.learning_phase()], [model.layers[layer].output,])
            activations = get_activations([X_batch,0])
            return activations

Comment: Congratulations on solving the problem. I'll learn the code, too.